# Prove that $f(x,y)=\frac{x^7y}{x^{14}+y^4}$ is bounded on $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |y| \geq 1\}$ but unbounded on elsewhere for $xy \neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $f(x,y)=\frac{x^7y}{x^{14}+y^4}$ is bounded on $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |y| \geq 1\}$ but unbounded on $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: xy \neq 0\}$

I've tried many methods for bounding the function when $|y| \geq 1$, but am having no luck, I just keep getting that $|f(x,y)| \leq |x|^7$. We've been learning about the open ball and open sets but I have no idea how that's got anything to do with this.

I have no idea where to start for the second question.

Comment: When $|y|\geq1$
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^7y}{x^{14}+y^4}\leq\frac{x^7y}{x^{14}+y^2}\leq\dfrac12$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By AM-GM we get
$$x^{14}+y^4\geq 2|x|^7y^2$$ so we get
$$\frac{|x|^7|y|}{x^{14}+y^4}\le \frac{|x|^7|y|}{2|x|^7|y|^2}=\frac{1}{2|y|}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! What about showing it's unbounded on $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: xy \neq 0 \}$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Because of the AM-GM inequality it is (under the assumption that $|y|\ge 1$)

$$|x^7y|\le \frac{x^{14}+y^2}{2}\le \frac{x^{14}+y^4}{2}.$$